# WordPress Customizer: Issue when open a section from a link in other section

Tags: wordpress

I have added 2 sections in Customizer, `Section A` and `Section B` for example. `Section A` is in `Panel X` and `Section B` isn't in any panel.

In `Section A`, I put a link: `<a href="#" class="go-to-section-b">Click here to show Section B</a>`

I can show `Section B` with my Jquery script:

```
$body.on( 'click', '.go-to-section-b', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( this ).closest( 'ul.customize-pane-child' ).removeClass( 'open' );
        $body.find( '#sub-accordion-panel-section_b' ).addClass( 'open' );
    } );
```

but the issue is when I click back button, it goes back to `Panel X`, not to Customizer main panel. Anyone has a good solution for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I use `api.section( 'section_b' ).focus();`